# Vim indentation for Erlang case statements

Tags: vim, erlang, neovim

I mainly develop Erlang in Neovim, and my organization's style guide specifies that each level of indentation should have 4 spaces. I have the following settings in my `vimrc`:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
```

This works great for almost every situation, except for the following example:

```erlang
Result = case function() of
             true -> 
                 success;
             false -> 
                 error
         end.
```

The lines after the case statement are offset relative to the `case` keyword. I'd like it instead to be indented like this:

```erlang
Result = case function() of
    true -> 
        success;
    false -> 
        error
end.
```

Is there any setting that could change this indentation behavior?

Comment: I tried the following plugins and couldn't get the indentation you were hoping for, unfortunately: https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-erlang-runtime, https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-erlang-runtime-red.

Comment: have you tried a erlang formatter?